# nHapi Add Non-Standard Segments to REFI12 Message

Tags: hl7, nhapi

I'm using nHapi to create & read HL7 REF_I12 messages in HL7 V2.3 and V2.4.

The standard nHapi REF_I12 Message is missing several segments I need - PRD, OBR, PV1, PV2, ORC and OBX.

How do I add these segments to the standard nHapi REF_I12 Message ?

Should I try and add them as custom Z segments ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I add these segments to the standard nHapi REF_I12 Message ?

You do not need to add those; those are there. You need to load them.

Just populating the message does not load the segment like `PID` in case of `REF^I12`. Please refer to the hierarchy [here](https://hl7-definition.caristix.com/v2/HL7v2.7/TriggerEvents/REF_I12):

> [image: Hierarchy]

You need to load `Provider_Contact` before loading `PRD` segment.

You can do it something like below:

```
msgREF_I12.GetPROVIDER_CONTACT(0).PRD......
```

You need to repeat the same for all the segments those are not loading. I think `ORC` is not the part of message; so this will not work with it.

Please refer to the source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/duaneedwards/nHapi/blob/master/NHapi20/NHapi.Model.V24/Message/REF_I12.cs#L137):

> ```
> ///<summary>
> /// Returns  first repetition of REF_I12_PROVIDER_CONTACT (a Group object) - creates it if necessary
> ///</summary>
> public REF_I12_PROVIDER_CONTACT GetPROVIDER_CONTACT()
> {
>     REF_I12_PROVIDER_CONTACT ret = null;
>     try
>     {
>         ret = (REF_I12_PROVIDER_CONTACT)this.GetStructure("PROVIDER_CONTACT");
>     }
>     catch(HL7Exception e)
>     {
>         HapiLogFactory.GetHapiLog(GetType()).Error("Unexpected error accessing data - this is probably a bug in the source code generator.", e);
>         throw new System.Exception("An unexpected error ocurred", e);
>     }
>     return ret;
> }
> ```

> Should I try and add them as custom Z segments ?

If you add [`Z`](https://corepointhealth.com/resource-center/hl7-resources/hl7-z-segments/) segment, it **will be** a Z segment. It will not be the segment you are expecting.